# Failed to lookup view ".." in views directory "views"?

Tags: node.js, forms, view, directory, connection

[image][image][image] hi this my nodejs code the server in vs is working but he cant see the hh file and get the form in browser

```
 const express= require('express')
 const app = express()
 const path =  require('path')
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
 app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express);
 app.set('views','views')
 app.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
     res.render('../views/hh')
 })
 app.post('/',(req,res,next)=>{
     MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/firstdb',(err,client)=>{
         const db = client.db()
         db.collection('users').insertOne({
             name: req.body.name,
             age:+req.body.age
         })
         client.close()
     })
 })
 app.listen(3000, ()=>{
     console.log('hi')
 })
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `hh` like so `res.render('hh')`? This assumes that the `hh.ejs` file is in `./views/hh.ejs` relative to the file with the code you posted.

Comment: yes i tried and it didnt work

Comment: Can you show your project folder structure?

Comment: i have added my project folder photo also package.json is in the same folder

Comment: If your code is in the `crud1.js` file then move it out to `D:/crud1.js` and it should work. Or try to set the views path to empty string like so `app.set('views','')`

Answer (score 0):

***Updated***

By default `ejs` template engine will look up into your `views` directory.

So, change your code: from `res.render('../views/hh')` to `res.render('hh')`.

Full code:

```
 const express= require('express')
 const app = express()
 const path =  require('path')
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

 app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

 app.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
     res.render('hh')
 })
 app.post('/',(req,res,next)=>{
     MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/firstdb',(err,client)=>{
         const db = client.db()
         db.collection('users').insertOne({
             name: req.body.name,
             age:+req.body.age
         })
         client.close()
     })
 })
 app.listen(3000, ()=>{
     console.log('hi')
 })
```

**Note**: Have a look on the sample project structure.

[image: Project structure]

Your app entry point i.e. `app.js`, `main.js`, `server.js` or any name you prefer that file & views folder both in the same path?

Your project structure should be (According to your latest project structure):

```
test-node-js-app
  - node_modules
  - views
     - hh.ejs
  - cr.js
  - packages.json
  - packages-lock.json
```

Comment: Are you sure that the pages are under `views` directory?

Comment: I have updated my answer. `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` Have a look there.

Comment: hi rashed i have copied your code and the browser says Cannot find module 'ejs'

Comment: Run into terminal `npm i ejs`. After this run your app. Finally make sure that project structure is the way i described (Seems that `crud.js` is the entry point of your app. Move it to outside the folder).

Comment: ok i run this in the terminal and gave me this error npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\views\package.json'
npm WARN views No description
npm WARN views No repository field.
npm WARN views No README data
npm WARN views No license field.

Comment: Can You please follow some steps? 1. Make an empty directory i.e. `test-node-js-app`. 2. `cd test-node-js-app` 3. `npm i express body-parser mongodb ejs` 4. Move all your current files as per discussion into that newly created directiry & 5. Finally run the app.

Comment: https://github.com/rashedrahat/memes-api Check this link to have an idea about project structure.

Comment: i followed the steps , make anew directory and move the code after  npm i express body-parser mongodb ejs

Comment: but still the same answer even after i moved hh.ejs too

Comment: Can you share your newly project structure and the code of main file i mean entry point server file.

Comment: i added the photo

Comment: I have gone through your photo. Aah bro. You didn't follow my instructions properly. Anyway, create a `views` named directory and move the`hh.ejs` inside that directory. See my attached photo as sample in my answer

Comment: i added the photo can u see it?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look into bottom. There i define the project structure.